# How to merge two or more bitmaps using NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a painting application that is running out of memory on a few devices really quick... :(

The problem is that I have bitmaps that are screen size and I'm loading 2 or 3 images to memory than I create a blank bitmap attached to a canvas for merging the 3 images into it. So yeah lot of bitmaps...

My goal is to use the NDK to load the images from file merge them and return only one Bitmap.  Well essentially in java I would create the empty image and pass the object to the NDK.  This should alleviate the amount of memory used on the device. At least in theory...

The first problem I'm facing is decoding the png image from file.  How can I do this via NDK? Should I use BitmapFactory via JNI?

Than the bigger question how do I merge these ARGB bitmaps?

Comment: I recommend that you have a look at the bitmap-plasma example in the NDK download. It does some similar-sounding things (loads and manipulates bitmaps through a native function).

Comment: Yeah I was looking at that code to use it as a base. The main deal is decode pngs merge their data into the passed blank bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with what image manipulation abilities are built into the NDK, but the OpenCV library can be included for use in the native code, and that is what I use (largely due to previous familiarity, but it is really nice).

Here's the [OpenCV 4 Android](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/OpenCV4Android) project. Here is how you would [open a PNG](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread).

Comment: I looked over the library but I'm not sure if it can merge pixel data? I see it can crop and re-size...

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of merge you want, but here is blending: http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html. Depending on the situation you may wish to write your own pixel manipulation algorithm, but here are also some common matrix manipulations: http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html.

Comment: OpenCV seems like it might do it... I'll try a couple things with it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I got OpenCv running on my app. It's a bit complicated to get started. Unfortunately there was no overlay option which is incredible they don't! So many awesome image manipulation and the easiest feature to make its not there! :( Anyways I'm using OpenCv to open image crop resize and I created my own overlay function.